# GAS-Clear cells if criteria is met

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to clear non-concurrent cells within a row if another cell within the same row equals "X"

So for example, if A3 equals "X", clear the contents of P3, U3, X3.

I would like this script to only run against one row at a time and only when that row is changed/updated.

I'm sure this is fairly simple for someone with some experience with GAS. I however am just starting out with Google apps and therefor GAS.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will not get anyone writing your code for you.  [Here is an example of `onEdit` with the edited range returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995262/how-can-i-return-the-range-of-an-edited-cell-using-an-onedit-event).  This is a good reference to start from.  Then it's just an `if` compare.

Comment: Here's your guidance. You can get started by checking the official [Apps Script docs for Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#). Checking for the values of a certain cell uses [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)) and [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue), and [clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clear)